# NSwag Inheritance and Polymorphism

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism, swagger, nswag

I have a model that I am serving up from a .NET Core appservice in Azure.

It contains a list property of derived types from a base type called Adjustment.

I have added the JsonInheritanceConverter and the KnownType attributes for each derived type, but when I look at the swagger document I don't see anything that indicates it is aware of the inheritance chain.

When I generate a service client the partial classes don't seem to be decorated with the JsonInheritanceConverter from this example on the repo: https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/Inheritance

Pretty sure I am just missing something like a switch when I generate my client from the swagger endpoint or something. Has anyone had this issue?

```
namespace AppService.DataAccess.Models
{
  public class Container: IBase
  {
      [Key]
      public int ID { get; set; }

      private List<Adjustment> _adjustments = new List<Adjustment>();

      public List<Adjustment> Adjustments 
      { 
        get
        {
          return _adjustments;
        }
      }
  }
}
```

namespace AppService.DataAccess.Models
{
  [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonInheritanceConverter), "discriminator")]
  [KnownType(typeof(Substitution))]
  [KnownType(typeof(Waiver))]
  [KnownType(typeof(Exemption))]
  public class Adjustment: IBase
  {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

  }
}

Comment: Looks good to me. Can you try to remove the interfaces?

Comment: Greetings. I will give that a try, but the IBase interface is used throughout the data model so I might not be able to. Quick question, a co-worker pointed out that NJsonSchema has it's own code generators, but we are using NSwag to generate clients. Will that work?

Comment: Ok I was able to pull the interface and the service is running. When I look at the generated swagger.json I don't see anything on the Adjustment definition that would indicate inheritance. So I guess regardless of the client generator I am still missing something.

Comment: Is it enough that I pulled the interface off of just the Adjustment class? I can't remove it from the container class or the service won't return the container. The IBase only has properties defined for my generic repositories.

Comment: This morning I knocked up another .Net Core app service and implemented the Container Animal Dog example. I am still not seeing the inheritance in the swagger.json. Could I be dealing with a tooling issue? Perhaps the version of NSwag we are using is out of date?

Comment: Hey Mr. Suter. I just plumbed our NSwag wrapper library and it looks like we are on version 11.3.1 of NSwag and 9.3.1 of NJsonSchema so I am pretty sure the issue is tooling based on your posted 12.0.0 release notes. Does that sound correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing our company wrapper project and the release notes for version 12.0.0 of NSwag we are confident that out of date tooling is the culprit here.

Comment: What "Tooling"?